# writing repository class to fetch data from 3 tables that are linked

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-framework-beans

I have 3 tables namely

Port_Register

```
Mobile_Number(Primary Key) | Gaining_Code(Foreign Key to Telecom_Codes) | Losing_Codes
```

Telecom_Codes

```
Telecom_Code(Primary Key) | Contact_Provider_Id(Foreign_Key to Contact_Provider)
```

Contact_Provider

```
Contact_Provider_Id | Contact_Name
```

`Gaining_Code` and `Losing_Code` are actually `Telecom_Code`

for the following scenario I have written entity classes which look like following

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Port_Register")
public class Port_Register {
    @Id
    @Column(name="MOBILE_NUMBER")
    private String mobile_Number;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="GAINING_CODE",referencedColumnName="TELECOM_CODE")
    private TelecomCodes gainingCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="LOSING_CODE",referencedColumnName="TELECOM_CODE")
    private TelecomCodes losingCSPCode;
}


    @Entity
    @Table(name="Telecom_Codes")
    public class TelecomCodes {

        @Id
        @Column(name="TELECOM_CODE")
        private String telecomCode;

        @OneToOne
        @Column(name = "CONTACT__Provider_Id")
        private ContactProvider contactProviderID;
    }
    @Entity
    @Table(name="ContactProvider")
    public class ContactProvider {
        @Column(name="CONTACT__Provider_Id")
        private String contactProviderId;

        @Column(name="CONTACT__Provider_NAME")
        private String ContactProviderName;
    }
```

I have to write a function in repository class to fetch data in the format

```
MobileNumber|Gaining_code|LosingCode| Gaining_provider_Name| Losing_provider_Name
```

All I know is for crud there is a predefined repository interface whose function gets to know abt implementation during run time.

so i created a repository that looks like

```
public interface PortOutRegisterRepository  extends CrudRepository< Ported_Register,String> {

//  public void store(T t);

//  public T retrieve(int id);

    //  public T delete(int id);
}
```

I thought I will call

```
PortOutRegisterRepository customRep;
List<Ported_Register> m=new ArrayList<Ported_Register>();
m=customRep.findall();
```

and then
I can use this to get individual info

```
 for(Ported_Register p:m)
    {
    p.getGainingCode().getContactProviderID().getContactName();
    }
```

But this is completely wrong.

Please help me on how i should write repository for this.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

CrudRepository allows you to find an item by passing in it's Id. 
[findById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-)

You can then get the individual info that you want from the object.

If you want to find all the items in the table, you could also use the 
`findAll()` method
[findAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findAll--)

edit: You have to make sure that there is to be referenced in the other tables.

Comment: Hi Dean, Thanks for reaching out. But can you please be a little more specific as to what I am supposed to do. and how I should go ahead writing repository class so as to get the reuqired details.

Comment: The way you have written the repository is quite ok, from what I've seen. You could use it this way and call the findById(id) method to get the particular item you're looking for. I'd be able to help you more if I could get a look at the class in which you intend to use the repository